# Print Fail: Partial Mess - What are possible causes?

Tags: creality-ender-3, pla, troubleshooting, extrusion

[image]

Can anyone help explain what might be wrong to do this? I am printing a bunch of the same item.

Comment: Which were the first and last items printed?

Comment: My initial thought was insufficient bed adhesion, but it looks like you have a PEI sheet which I am not very familiar with its adhesion capabilities.

Comment: @PerryWebb It started in the middle and I think went clockwise layer by layer, but I didn't want everything.

Comment: @agarza Typically, prints are stuck pretty well to the bed, but come to think of it I haven't had anything print to the left side of the board much and it all seems to be that side. Maybe this is a slight level issue causing bed adhesion problems. I'll play around with it. Thanks!

Comment: @Doug I recall seeing an unboxing video recently where the reviewer was having a slight issue with the PEI sheet. After washing it with dish soap, the sheet was gripping the prints again. Just a thought.